# Using MUI with Tailwindcss (and NextJS). How to fix transparent button problem while still keep using tailwindcss preflight

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

I am building a project over a NextJS template which uses TailwindCSS. The thing is I want to use MUI components with it but when I tried adding a button I get the transparent button ([unexpected behavior when using Tailwind, and MUI in NextJS Project (White Button error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536210/unexpected-behavior-when-using-tailwind-and-mui-in-nextjs-project-white-button)).

I am aware of the existing solutions which involves setting preflight to false under corePlugins, but doing that in my case breaks the template's layout. The template already uses tailwindcss deeply with extensions over its base preflight.

I want to know if there is any effective way to fix problems with MUI components while still not completely removing tailwind's preflight.

(If you think there is any comparable react components library which will not conflict with tailwind's preflight please feel free to share.)

Comment: remove preflight and your own changed preflight.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight
https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@%5E3/src/css/preflight.css

Answer (score 2):

I found me in same dilema. If I disable preflight (as recommended) I end up loosing base style in every non-mui components.

This is my suggested solution, using classes added by MUI to buttons:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

button.MuiButton-containedPrimary {
  @apply bg-blue-800;
}
```

The problem is the "background-color: transparent" added in tailwind base. So here, I'm overriding it to MUI buttons